# Confused which joomla module to use

Tags: templates, module, joomla1.5

I am trying to use the ja_nickel template in my site. It can be previewed in: 
http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#templates.joomlart.com/ja_nickel

I am trying to show my latest news in the top information block. It consists of title, thumbnail image and some text. So dun know which one module to use?

any idea will be helpful.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the core Joomla! newsfeed option. It pulls from articles and organizes it by the latest article created via the timestamp.